# Sequences: $\frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|}\to0$ implies $x_n\to0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence.

If $\frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|}\to0$ can you follow $x_n\to0$?

Clearly it is enough to show $|x_n|\to0$ but how can you estimate the fraction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that $\frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|}=1-\frac1{1+|x_n|}$. Hence you get $\frac1{1+|x_n|}\to 1$, then the reciprocal ${1+|x_n|}\to 1$ and ultimately $|x_n|\to 0$.

Comment: This is like what is called a perfect day: tremendously satisfying!!

Comment: This is probably the dumbest question of them all. Can you explain the technique you used to find the given equality? I'm rusty :(. This is such a beautiful answer lol.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$.  The inverse of this function (where defined, i.e., where $x\ne-1$) is $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$, which is continuous (where defined, i.e., where $x\ne 1$).  Thus $f(|x_n|)\to 0$ implies
$$ |x_n| = f^{-1}(f(|x_n|))\to f^{-1}(0) = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

If by contradiction $|x_n|\to0$ is false, then $|x_n|\to l\neq0,|x_n|\to+\infty$ or doesen't admit limit. In any of these possibilities $\frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|}\to0$ would fail. Absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$.  $\;\;$Since $\displaystyle\frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|}\to0,$

$\;\; \displaystyle\frac{|x_n|}{1+|x_n|}<\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$  for $n\ge N\;$ and so $\;\;|x_n|<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N\;\;$  (for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$).

Therefore $x_n\to0$.